# Regex to exclude number pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have the following script that is meant to pull out record ID's within parentheses.  It is also meant to ignore other details that are within parenthesis.  I am running into an issue with a detail like this (YYYY-DD) where I am not sure how to exclude this, as I need to keep other Record ID's that do include '-'.  The script also starts from the end which is important.

script:

```
df1['Doc ID'] = df['Folder Path'].str.extract('.*\((?!Data Only)(.*)\).*',expand=True)
```

I have tried adding:

```
[^\d\d\d\d-\d\d], (?!date_format) and neither work
```

please look at the 3rd instance, this is where my problem lies:

```
  Folder Path                                               Doc ID
1 report/global/(Data Only)/admin (245)                     245 #245 is kept, 'Data Only' successfully ignored
2 report/regional(PRSP)/tech/(121,130,505 - RETIRED)/2018   121,130,505 - RETIRED #successfully ignores (PRSP)
3 global/report/admin (505)/(2018-03)                       2018-03 #I cannot figure out how to avoid 2018-03 or any YYYY-DD sequence and only grab 505 in this instance
```

Comment: As I was trying to answer your question, I realized I do not find the problem well defined. What is the algorithm you have in mind to decide which parentheses to extract the text from?

Comment: The folder path goes in order of granularity, and I am trying to find the Record ID that is in the last directory that is referenced.  Unfortunately, there are also text and (YYYY-MM) issues that i am dealing with.  The code represented starts from right to left and grabs whatever is in the parenthesis.  At this point, i just need to avoid the string sequence (YYYY-MM) and add this into my current script.  So i am trying to find a modular fix to add into the current code that i have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start from the right, you should express it in your RE. I would suggest this as a starting point:

```
df1['Doc ID'] = df['Folder Path'].str.extract('\(([^(]*?)\)[^)]*$',expand=True)
```

But this suffers from matching the date, so let us insert a subpattern for that as well:

```
df1['Doc ID'] = df['Folder Path'].str.extract('\(([^(]*?)\)[^)]*(?:\(\d{4}-\d{2}\))?[^)]*$',expand=True)
```

Comment: tif you're are a genius!! Thank you so much for your help!